# Windows 7 computer forgets one of its administrative share after restart

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

This computer is used for 5 years or more, OS: Windows 7.
Since a few weeks the computer forgets one of its administrative shares after restart.

I can re-add the share using

> net share g$=g:\ /GRANT:myname, FULL

but then after restart is gone.

The other two admin share is OK:

- C$ : OK
- E$ : OK (external USB drive)
- G$ : forgot (external USB drive)

**Question:**

What possibly happened and how can I get back my g$ permanently?

Answer (score -1):

the only thing I can think off is that the command is missing something. Try to add first via GUI (my computer->map network drive-> type the path) then put a CHECK on "Reconnect at logon". Then try to restart pc, if it's still there even after the restart, then the command you're using is not sufficient enough :)
Edit: try to add /PERSISTENT or /P:Yes....this means that you're making the shared folder permanent, even after restart.

Comment: "Reconnect at logon". is appropriate on a client computer which connects to the shared resource not on the server which shares the resource

Comment: Yah, please edit your question, you mentioned that the OS is windows 7, anyone will assume that you are pertaining to the client and not to the server in which I've assumed :D